# Google Cloud Identity: Group Managers cannot delete group members

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-groups, google-cloud-identity

I am listed as `MANAGER` in a group that I am managing on a Google Cloud Platform organisation via the IAM Groups interface on https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/groups.

But they delete icon is greyed out, and displaying a message:

> You need the following permissions to be granted by a group administrator for this action:
> Required permission(s): `cloudidentity.memberships.remoMemberRole`

The message links to a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console), that has no helpful information nor mentions the problem described in the message.

AFAIK, as a manager of a group, one should be able to add and remove members.

Can you help me fix or explain this issue?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Are you organization's administrator? From this messege you are missing `cloudidentity.memberships.remoMemberRole`. It might be took off from you due to less privilage rule and only owner can do it. If you will enter [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10284003?hl=en) you have information that you `have` or you `don't have` proper permissions? Also could you ask your Organization's administrator to add you `cloudidentity.memberships.remoMemberRole`?

Comment: Thanks @PjoterS for having a look. So I want to clarify, since this does not match my perception of the role "MANAGER" on such groups. In my point of view, the MANAGER of a Google Group should be able to add or remove members of this group.

In the case of the screenshot above, I am MANAGER of that group.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I do not have to be Organization Administrator to add or remove members from a Group in which I am setup as MANAGER.

I can add members to the group. But I cannot remove members from the group.
What is the point of the MANAGER role in a group, when the manager can only add members?

Because if I switch myself to be the OWNER of the group, I can add, remove members BUT I can also delete the group itself.

And that is where I thought MANAGER comes into play. A manager should add/remove members, but not be able to delete the group itself.

Comment: Did you enable `Groups for Business` in `Admin Console`? Did you create this group or were you added later by someone? Per [Assign roles to a group's members](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167094?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanager) Document, `Manager` should have this permission by default and should be able to remove and add users to the group. Roles with `cloudidentity` are not available in IAM as per [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console#group-permissions). Maybe the Group owner revoked this one specific permission using the Admin Console?

Comment: @PjoterS I see. So the group was created by a special service account, who is assigned Groups Admin in Google Workspace. The service account then appoints individuals as `Manager`. Yes, I am under the same impression, `Manager` should have the permission to add and remove users of a group by default. However, the group owner did nothing to revoke or alter these rights. Do you know how I can inspect the API for any problems with the group and group membership being created there?

Comment: This issue got resolved. It was an UI bug and got fixed by the Cloud Console team. I can no longer reproduce it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got resolved. It was an UI bug and got fixed by the Cloud Console team. I can no longer reproduce it.